# Finding all ideals in $\mathbb{Q}[x]/I$, where $I$ is the ideal generated by $p(x)=x^2(x^2+x+1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-verification, ideals

I want to find all ideals in $\mathbb{Q}[x]/I$, where $I$ is the ideal generated by $p(x)=x^2(x^2+x+1)$. I know that $$\mathbb{Q}[x]/I \cong \mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2) \times \mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2+x+1)$$

I have found three ideals so far:

$1) J_1=$Ideal generated by $(1,0)$ which is prime and maximal

$2)J_2=$ Ideal generated by $(x,0)$ which is prime but not maximal, since $J_2 \subsetneq J_1 \subsetneq \mathbb{Q}[x]/I $

$3)J_3=$ Ideal generated by $(0,1)$ which is prime and maximal

Note that Ideal generated by $(0,x)$ (denote it by $J_4$) is exactly $J_3$, because : $$ J_4 \ni (0,x)\cdot(0,x)+(0,x)=(0,x^2)+(0,x)=(0,-1-x)+(0,x)=(0,-1)$$ Hence $J_3=J_4$.

My question is : Are there any other ideals in $\mathbb{Q}[x]/I$ ? If yes are they prime/maximal ?

I would be thankful if you verify the following proof of the question : "is $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2+x+1)$ a field or not?"

Since $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is a Euclidean domain , and hence a P.I.D, and since $x^2+x+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$(because it has no roots in $\mathbb{Q}$) $(x^2+x+1)$ is prime and maximal, Therefore $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2+x+1)$ is a field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ideals in $\mathbb{Q}[x]/I$ correspond to the ideals in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ that contain $I$.

These are principal ideals generated by the divisors of $x^2(x^2+x+1)$.

There are $(2+1)\cdot(1+1)$ such divisors. Find them.

This is similar to finding the ideals of $\mathbb{Z}/I$ when $I=(p^2 q)$, where $p$ and $q$ are prime numbers.

Comment: Thanks ! Let me see if I got it right: Ideals in $\mathbb{Z}/I$ are (p),(p^2),(q),(pq), (1), (p^2q)... 

Moreover, Can you please explain further why : the ideals in $\mathbb{Q}[x]/I$ correspond to (non-trivial) ideals in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ that (properly) contain $I$ ?

Comment: @the8thone, the correspondence is given by the ring homomorphism theorems.

Comment: Thanks ! Intuitively I can see that, but my intuition gives me 4 (not 6) choices : $(p),(p^2),(q),(pq)$, because $(1)=\mathbb{Z}$  and $(p^2q)/(p^2q) = 0$
What am I missing here?

Comment: @the8thone, you're not missing anything, just refusing to count the zero ideal and the whole ring as ideals, which they are.